# how to create product auto Code generator python django

Tags: python, django

I have a product class in the Django model. Over there are product name, category and department name (foreign key).

So I want to create an automatic code generator that will generate automatically like 2 or 3 alphabets as category name and  3 alphabet department name and 6 digits number; for example: `COM-ELC-000001`

```
class Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank =True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    item_choice = (
        ('IT','IT'), 
        ('Electronics', 'Electronics'),
    )
    item_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank =True, choices = item_choice )
    code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null =True,blank=True)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete = models.SET_NULL,null= True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Ok, you explained some things that you have. What have you tried so far? And since you used the tag, how is AJAX part of this?

Comment: oh my bad. I have corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Your Models

```
class Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank =True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    item_choice = (
        ('IT','IT'), 
        ('Electronics', 'Electronics'),
    )
    item_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank =True, choices = item_choice )
    code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null =True,blank=True)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete = models.SET_NULL,null= True, blank=True)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        code = "%s %s" % (self.item_name[:3], self.item_choice) 
        super(Item, self).save(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Can you be more elaborate to get the point of view? I used it but it did not work.

Comment: It shows nothing actually what I give input into the code field that's only shown in the item list. Like no item_name and no item_type in the code.

i added this into my item class:
'''
    def save(self, **kwargs):
        code = "%s %s" % (self.name[:3], self.item_type)
        super(Item, self).save(**kwargs)
'''
what else can I do? I'm a newbie that's why need the help and no idea of it

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/add-the-slug-field-inside-django-model/

You Can Implement as like it

Comment: **TypeError at /item_entry
'NoneType' object is not callable
Request Method: POST
Request URL: /item_entry
Django Version: 3.0.3
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
'NoneType' object is not callable**  

this error after using save function 
@Shakil